# In Islam, are Christians considered to be idolaters?

Tags: shirk, christianity

In Islam, are Christians considered to be idolaters?
If it isn't considered idolatry, my question is why? Christians believe a person (Jesus) is God.

Comment: Christians are considered to be *kafir* and *mushrik*  (see [5:72](https://quran.com/5/72)). Idolatry is sometimes considered a synonym of the latter (shirk). However idolatry is also often understood as worship of pagan deities and specifically of statues and images. Maybe you should elaborate your question?

Comment: Is worship a person not idolatry?

Comment: If by idolatry you mean shirk (associating someone with Allah) then yes Christians do shirk, there can be no two opinions on it.

Comment: Yes, I do. Then my question is why Quaran let Christian live under Jaziya while it doesn't allow other religions to be so? (It's kind of a privilege for Jewish and Christians only as far as I understand. All the rest (according to the sharia) have the choice to be Muslim or to die, because they doesn't believe in one God. (while the Christian also don't believe in one God)

Comment: @UmH Please don't answer questions in comments (see on [our meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1776/answers-on-comment-section) with further links). Comments are for clarification in first place and not meant to last forever!

Answer (score 1):

There are Christians who - reading the Word of God in the Bible - came to the same Message as we find it in the Quran. There is a quite explicit passage in the Bible, and many other indications that Jesus clearly said that he is *not* God.

Gospel of Mark, 10:17-18

> And as he was setting out on his journey, a man ran up and knelt
> before him, and asked him, "Holy1 Teacher, what must I do to inherit
> eternal life?" And Jesus said to him, "Why do you call me holy? No one
> is holy but God alone.

Witnesses of Jehova and Unitarians reject the trinity dogma and pray to God only.

Reformed and Presbytarian Churches only accept the teachings of the Bible. Members are allowed to accept the trinity dogma but it is not part of reformed theology. Images in churches and praying to persons other than God are forbidden. (many other Protestant churches do pray to Jesus).

The Oriental Church was originally also rather Unitarian; many unitarian Christians have supported the Prophet and accepted Islam. The acceptance of Christians is also to be seen on this background.

Other Churches do not understand Jesus as a deity other than God, but that Jesus and the Holy Spirit are manifestations of the same God. This teaching is clearly told to be wrong (shirk) in the Quran but somehow not estimated the same as worshipping other deities.

Comment: other contributions, see also https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/61387/are-christians-considered-to-be-idolatry/65518#65518